contactless payment (EMV transactions)
I have a question regarding the contactless payments system. I want to develop a payment poss device using the CLRC663 chip and stm32 MCU. As I know I need some payment gateway (like Paypal, Stripe, or Adyen) where I will gonna send retrieved data from card by CLRC663. So I have several questions regarding this:

What type of data should I read from the card, (A) how is it possible, as I know we can access to PAN number and expiration date. (B) Is that enough to process the payment?
Which gateways will allow me to do such operations?
Is it possible without extra licenses and paperwork?

If anyone has done such project or worked in a similar field please let me know the possibilities of this crazy idea.

This question is similar to: APDU commands to get data from NFC tag using ISODEP. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. A lot of the answer to this is platform independent, so answer like this should help.
